# Differentiability of a piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis

I know that there are a couple of these questions already asked on this forum, and I've checked all of them out but neither of them seems to answer my question. The problem simply states:

$$\text{Is the following function differentiable } \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$$

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} \ln(3+|x|) - \frac{x}{3} - \ln3 &x<0 \\ 0 & x=0 \\x^2(2+\sin(\frac{1}{x}) & x>0 
\end{cases}$$

So I first checked the continuity of the function, and there were no problems there:

$$ \lim_{x \to 0^-}f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^-}{(\ln(3+|x|) - \frac{x}{3} - \ln3 )} = \ln3 - \ln3 = 0 $$
$$ \lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^+}{x^2(2 + \sin(\frac{1}{x}))} =  \lim_{x \to 0^+}{(2x^2 + x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x}))} = ... \text {squeeze theorem ... } = 0 $$
Therefore:
$$  \lim_{x \to 0^-}f(x) =  \lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x) = f(0) = 0$$
So the function is continuous.  Now, for the differentiability:

$$ f'(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{3-x} - \frac{1}{3} & x<0 \\0 &x=0 \\ 2x(2+ \sin(\frac{1}{x}))-\cos(\frac{1}{x}) & x>0 \end{cases}$$

Here's the part that confuses me:
$$ f'(0) = \begin{cases} 0 & x<0 \\0 & x = 0 \\ \text{not defined} & x<0  \end{cases}$$

So I guess this tells me that the function is not differentiable at x = 0.

But how come I can then directly evaluate the derivative at x = 0?.

I guess what I'm really  confused about is the definition of differentiability. If I say

$$\text{The function }f \text{ is differentiable at } x = 0 \text{.}$$
Is that equivalent to:

$$f'_{-}(0) = f'_{+}(0) = f(0)$$
or
$$\lim_{x \to 0^-}f'(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^+}f'(x) = f'(0) $$
or simply that the derivative at x = 0 can be evaluated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the derivative defined?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: How do you calculate the derivative at $x=0?$

Comment: Well if f(x) = 0 when x = 0 then f'(x) = 0 when x = 0? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Does the slope depend solely on the point of interest?

Comment: I guess not, mind explaining a bit further?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Rigorous_definition

Comment: Take $f(x)=x$ at $x=0$. You claim that because $f(0)=0$ it follows that $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: Yeah, that actually makes sense. So I guess I'm supposed to find the derivative by definition?

Comment: Right. It should be 'easy' looking at the left side limit, where you can use work you already did. The complicated part is the right side limit.

Comment: I don't really get it again. If I were to look for the derivative when x>0 of this function by definition, wouldn't I just end up with the same thing that I would've gotten without using the definition?

Comment: Actually @Ingix , I just realized that your analogy was not correct. I'm not claiming that because f(0) = 0 therefore f'(0) = 0. I'm claiming that since f(x) = 0 when x = 0, then f'(x) = 0, when x = 0.
Consider this: What if f was defined as f(x) = 5, when x = 3 (for example 3 is the critical point here). Then when x = 3, f'(x) = 0. Therefore f'(3) = 0

Comment: 1. The problematic point is $x=0$. For all the other $x$-values the function is not really piece-wise, because the definition of the derivative is only interested what happens in an arbitrary small neighbourhood of $x$.In those cases the function is essentially the $x<0$ branch or the $x > 0$ branch, and you calculated the derivates there correctly. What you need to do now is actually looking at $\lim_{h \to 0^-}\frac{\ln(3+|h|)−\frac{h}3−\ln3}h$ and $\lim_{h \to 0^+}\frac{h^2(2+\sin(\frac1h))}h$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83211/discussion-between-koy-and-ingix).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you should show **by definition** that 
$$
f_+'(0) = f'_-(0), 
$$
then $f'(0)$ would exists. If not then the function is not differentiable

Here is a proposition:

> if $f$ is differentiable on a deleted neighborhood of $x =c$, and $f'(c^+) = f'(c^-)$ both exists, then $f'(c)$ exists, and equals to such limit.

There are counterexamples that when $f'(0^+)$ and  $f'(0^-)$ not all exists, $f'(0)$ still could exist.